# Python optparse metavar

Tags: python, optparse

I am not sure what `optparse`'s `metavar` parameter is used for. I see it is used all around, but I can't see its use.

Can someone make it clear to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As @Guillaume says, it's used for generating help. If you want to have an option that takes an argument, such as a filename, you can add the `metavar` parameter to the `add_option` call so your preferred argument name/descriptor is output in the help message. From [the current module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#generating-help):

```
usage = "usage: %prog [options] arg1 arg2"
parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)
parser.add_option("-f", "--filename",
                  metavar="FILE", help="write output to FILE"),
```

would produce help like this:

```
usage: <yourscript> [options] arg1 arg2

options:
  -f FILE, --filename=FILE
```

The "FILE" after the "-f" and the "--filename" comes from the metavar.

Answer (score 5):

metavar seems to be used for generating help : http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/optparse-generating-help.html

Comment: metavar="helpfulname" customizes the help message with a helpful  name;  different from the dest="name".  The dest="name" might not be helpful to users.

Answer (score 0):

`metavar` is a variable used for print in the screen after option. Usually used for suggestion input after option are `FILE` or `INT` or `STRING` to user. Without `metavar`, `optparse` will print `dest` value after option you've been added.

Answer (score 0):

There's another meaningful use of metavar where one desires to use 'dest' as the argument lookup-tag but mask the help message by metavar. (E.g. sometimes handy when using subparsers). (As indicated in the comment of [S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott)).

```
parser.add_argument(
        'my_fancy_tag',
        help='Specify destination',
        metavar='helpful_message'
        )
```

or equally

```
parser.add_argument(
        dest='my_fancy_tag',
        help='Specify destination',
        metavar='helpful_message'
        )
```

Help will show the metavar:

```
./parse.py -h usage: parser [-h] destination

positional arguments:   
  helpful_message  Specify destination
```

but dest will store the fancy_tag in Namespace:

```
./parse.py test 
Namespace(my_fancy_tag='test')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's now preferable to use the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) library instead of optparse.

Reasons why are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217673/why-use-argparse-rather-than-optparse).