# Using getopt() to get values passed from the command line

Tags: python, unix, command-line, command-line-arguments, getopt

I am writing a Python script to create directories for a given term and course. I would like to make use of the Python modules os, sys, and getopt (with both short and long form options) so that the running script would look like:

```
>python directory.py –t fall2013 –c cs311-400 
>python directory.py –-term fall2013 –-class cs311-400
```

The code that I have write now looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import getopt

term = ""
course = ""

options, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 't:c:', ['term=', 'course='])

for opt, arg in options:
    if opt in ('-t', '--term'):
        term = arg
    elif opt in ('-c', '--course'):
         course = arg
```

After this, I have a function that takes in the term and course an uses os.mkdir and such:

```
def make_folders(term, course):
    if not os.path.isdir(term + course):
        os.mkdir(term + course)
        path = os.path.join(term + course, "assignments")
        os.makedirs(path)

        path = os.path.join(term + course, "examples")
        os.makedirs(path)

        path = os.path.join(term + course, "exams")
        os.makedirs(path)

        path = os.path.join(term + course, "lecture_notes")
        os.makedirs(path)

        path = os.path.join(term + course, "submissions")
        os.makedirs(path)

make_folders(term, course)
```

For some reason, the folder that gets made only has a name that represents the term rather than both the term and the course. I feel like this might have something to do with my use of getopt, but I'm not certain. Any advice?

Comment: I think getopt is deprecated in python2.7 http://stackoverflow.com/a/3217687/2530083 use `argparse` instead

Comment: As a side comment, do you realise that `path = os.path.join(whatever)` and `os.makedirs(path)` lines are repeated? Refactor it with `for` looping through a list of dirs `["assignments", "examples", "exams", "lecture_notes", "submissions"]`.

Comment: @rtrwalker `optparse` is deprecated. `getopt` is kept for C users.

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join` is a clever function. Just pass as many folders as you need:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join("first", "second", "third")
'first/second/third'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in your class; at least I'm almost positive I am. Was running into this exact problem and was having trouble getting that sub-directory. A google search landed me here! Well, after a few more googles and LOTS of troubleshooting, found the answer to our problem!

```
os.makedirs(''+term+'/'+course+'')      
path = os.path.join(''+term+'/'+course+'', "exams")
os.makedirs(path)
```

That should clean it up for you and give your your new directory and sub-directories! Good luck with the rest of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `term + course`, Python concatenates the strings in `term` and `course` directly, before `os.path.join()` even sees them.  That is, if, say, `term == "fall2013"` and `course == "cs311-400"`, then `term + course == "fall2013cs311-400"` with nothing in between.

One way around that would be to insert an explicit slash between the term and the course, as in `term + "/" + course`.  However, since you've presumably been instructed to use [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) (which is a good idea, anyway), you can just pass *all* the path components you want to join to it as separate arguments and let it take care of joining them for you:

```
path = os.path.join(term, course, "exams")
```

Also, a few tips for your assignment, and for good Python coding in general:

- While the [`getopt`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) module is not actually deprecated like rtrwalker claims in the comments, you're probably better off using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) unless you *have* to use `getopt` for some reason (like, say, the assignment tells you to).
- Your code looks very repetitive.  Repetitive code is a ["smell"](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) that should suggest the need for a loop, perhaps like this:

  ```
  dirs = ("assignments", "examples", "exams", "lecture_notes", "submissions")
  for folder in dirs:
      path = os.path.join(term, course, folder)
      os.makedirs(path)
  ```