# in "(options, args) = parser.parse_args" what value does args contains

Tags: python

```
option_list = [
    make_option("-i", "--adapter", action="store",
        type="string", dest="dev_id"),
    make_option("-b", "--device", action="store",
        type="string", dest="address"),
            ]
parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list)
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

In the above code snippet, what value does `args` contain?

1. when I try to print `len(args)`, I am getting `0` even though I am passing 2 arguments via command line
2. when I  try to print just `args` it just prints `[]`.

what actually is the use of that parameter and what does it contain?

Comment: Unless you are specifically wanting to support python <=2.6, suggest you forget optparse and learn argparse instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217673/why-use-argparse-rather-than-optparse ;)

Comment: " I am passing 2 arguments"... I don't think so. You are probably passing 2 *options*.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html):

> `parse_args()` returns two values:
>
> - `options`, an object containing values for all of your options—e.g. if `--file` takes a single string argument, then `options.file` will be the filename supplied by the user, or `None` if the user did not supply that option
> - `args`, the list of positional arguments leftover after parsing options

In your case, `len(args) == 0` because all of the arguments you pass are parsed into `options`.

Comment: jonrsharpe, thanks for your response.
 when i print len(args),will it be '0' always?

Comment: @Jyothi not necessarily, it depends whether there are any arguments left over after parsing the options