# Sorting the command line arguments entered by user in our predefined way

Tags: python, optparse

I have defined some of the options using `optparse` for my python script. In my script the user enters command line arguments in any order, but I want to sort in my predefined way. Let's say the user enters the following arguments:

```
scriptname -g gvalue -n nvalue -s svalue -k kvalue -e evalue
```

When the user enters the above parameters in any order, I want to sort in the following manner:

```
-s svalue -g gvalue -k kvalue -n nvalue -e evalue
```

Ultimately I need the above order at any time.

Comment: I don't understand; opt parse will give you the arguments by name, regardless of the original order.

Comment: you use actions different from "store action" in your optparse configuration? (namely "callback")

Comment: Why do you need to sort them? You could sort them but it's really unneeded. Also, [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html), optparse is deprecated.

Comment: Also see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217673) on why to use `argparse` instead of `optparse`.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways to get what you want. You shouldn't need to do this. But here's the fix:

I'm going to use `argparse` because `optparse` is deprecated.
This code will show `None` if the user has not specified a value for that argument

```
## directory user$ ./argparse_ex.py -s foo -g bar -k quox -n woo -e testing123

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sorted Arguments')
parser.add_argument('-s', help='I will be printed if the user types --help')
parser.add_argument('-g', help='I will be printed if the user types --help')
parser.add_argument('-k', help='I will be printed if the user types --help')
parser.add_argument('-n', help='I will be printed if the user types --help')
parser.add_argument('-e', help='I will be printed if the user types --help')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

sorted_args = [args['s'], args['g'], args['k'], args['n'], args['e']]
print sorted_args

## ['foo', 'bar', 'quox', 'woo', 'testing123']
```

**[argparse documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/optparse.html) is defined with commands for each value such as:

```
parser.add_option("-k", action="store", type="string", dest="kvalue")
```

and executed as:

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Then `options.kvalue` will contain the relevant user-inputted argument for `-k`. Then the sequence in order could be generated:

```
( getattr(options,name) for name in ('svalue', 'gvalue', 'kvalue', 'nvalue', 'evalue') )
```

Alternatively, string comparisons on the raw `argv` can achieve the same thing without using `optparse`.