# Python optparse from method call?

Tags: python, scope, arguments, optparse

I have two python scripts with the following structure:

```
# Script1.py
from optparse import OptionParser
def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-a", "--add-foobar", action="store_true", help="set foobar true",
        dest="foobar", default=False)
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    print options.foobar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Script2.py
from Script1 import main as script1Main
def main():
    script1Main()
```

Is there a way to pass command line arguments from script 2 to script 1? Script 1 in this example is immutable, therefore this must be done only thorough optparse.

Comment: I'm confused...how are you calling the scripts and why are you doing it this way? Why do you say that Script 1 is "immutable?"

Comment: Both of these scripts have the executable bit set. They would be run in the command line (For example, *./Script1.py -a* or *./Script2.py*). Script 1 is immutable as in I cannot change the code in script 1. As to the why, that's a very good question! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass any arguments to `parse_args`, it just uses the value of `sys.argv[1:]`, which is going to be whatever arguments were passed when you called `Script2.py`. The fact that `Script2.py` calls `Script1.main` doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, maybe use [argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217673/why-use-argparse-rather-than-optparse) instead. You can process all arguments in script 2, then pass the argument handle to script 1.

```
# Script1.py
def main(args):
    print args

# Script2.py
import argparse
from Script1 import main as script1Main

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    parser.add_option("-a", "--add-foobar", action="store_true", help="set foobar true", default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    script1Main(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```