# Regex parse a command line string but don't return spaces between quotes

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am using python to parse a string that is passed in by the optparse module. 
I want to split the string on certain delimiters but not in between quote marks. 
A sample string is:

```
--state-basedir /dir/dir/dir/ --cmd=\"param load $v2param\" --master=/dev/ttyUSB0 --console --map --out=udp:192.168.1.1:14550
```

This string is passed in as a single optparse argument, I am then going to pass it to another process. 
I have been trying various things at http://pythex.org/
The closest I have gotten is:

```
`(?<!")[\s=](?![\s0-9a-zA-Z\$\\]*")`
```

The issue is that the `=` sign after `--cmd` and the space before `--master` are not matched.

In plain English, this is how I am reading my regex:

> match either a space character or an equal character as long as it is not preceded by a quotation mark and as long as it is not proceeded by a combination of any other letter,numbers,punctuation **and** another quotation mark

I had a feeling that there was something else I was missing, like greediness, so I tried adding `?` after my look-ahead and look-behind terms. If I put a `?` after my look-behind one I can get the space before `--master` but if I put the `?` after my look-ahead term I get the spaces in the quotation marks now, which I don't want.

The idea here is that I am going to use re.split to handle things.

Thanks for any explanations as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: See [Why use argparse rather than optparse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217673/why-use-argparse-rather-than-optparse)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for that, but I don't think my issue is necessarily a limitation of optparse. I am calling a different python script with my example as a single string. This single string is what I have to parse to pass on to another process. I am trying to fix a small issue I am having with the mavproxy.py script for use with drones

Comment: Well, I see, the point I am trying to make is that parsing command line arguments with regex is a real pain and since there are better options, you'd better stick with them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ahh my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regex answer and it's also not pretty, but it is one line.

```
 sum([[x] if '"' in x else re.split(' |=',x) for x in re.split('=(\".+?\" )',a)],[])
```

output:

```
['--state-basedir', '/dir/dir/dir/', '--cmd', '"param load $v2param" ', '--master', '/dev/ttyUSB0', '--console', '--map', '--out', 'udp:192.168.1.1:14550']
```

Starting from the `re.split('=(\".+?\" )',a)]` this splits out text surrounded by quotes (more specifically `="something another thing"`). The split pieces are then split further with `re.split(' |=',x)` if they do not have a `"` in them, or are just returned as is `[x]` if they do. The last step is collapsing the resulting 2d list by overloading `sum` with `sum(two_d_list,[])`.

I hope this answer helps but I understand if it isn't what you're looking for